# Passing data from my NodeJS back to React component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React component which is GaleryPage and i want to show a list of information i found them with my Back end side which are file_name and Type_contract .This is my back End side code :

```
app.post('/convert',  upload.single('file'),(req, res) =>{
if(req.file){
   let file= req.file.filename
    let Type_contract = 'Contract'
    let file_name = path.basename(file,path.extname(file))
    console.log(file_name);
    console.log(Type_contract);

}
 res.redirect('/');
```

and here is my React component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


class GaleryPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file_name: '',
      Type_contract:''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    const data = new FormData();

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/upload',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
      .then((file_name,Type_contract) => this.setState({
        file_name: file_name,
        Type_contract:Type_contract
      })
    )}

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
       <ul>
           <li file_name={this.state.file_name}>file_name= 
     {this.state.file_name}</li>


           <li Type_contract={this.state.Type_contract}>Type_contract= 
           {this.state.Type_contract}</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
            );
            }
         }

  export default GaleryPage;
```

when i try this code i find always empty page and no data is not  showning

Comment: Check your response object ... mainly this `.then((file_name,Type_contract) `. You're now just trying to set the state, but do you even know what `file_name,Type_contract` contain from the response?! I think that there should be only one response there as a `JSON` and not two as you have now. Check the docs here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html . It will help you understand better.

Comment: Also, in your express code I don't see any part where your actually send the data.

Comment: i'm sorry i am new at React Js and Node Js to send data i tried res.json() but it's still the same problem

Comment: try this : fetch(url).then(
response => response.json()
).then(response => { console.log(response)})

Comment: Have you checked if the data is set in your express server endpoint? Also, the back-end code you posted has a different endpoint set than you're calling in React(in express you have `convert` and in React you have `upload`

Comment: the route  it's not the problem because both of the routes /convert and /upload have the same code but even i replaced it it still the same problem i get file_name : empty field and there isno data loaded